# If banned for life from entering USA for misrepresentation can we apply Canada PR through Express entry

Tags: visa, canada, pr

If USA non-immigrant H-1B visa got refused for  misrepresentation under (212(a)(6)(C)(i)) and banned for life to enter the USA, does that USA visa refusal will have impact in applying for Canada PR through express entry. what are the chances of getting approval or rejection of the Canada Visa (PR)?

Please let know if anybody got banned for life for misrepresentation from USA got Canada visa or PR.

Comment: @mlc Expanded a little, and done!

Comment: Of course I do not know your circumstances but ~20% of these 212(a)(6)(C)(i) findings are either rescinded or get waivers. Unless of course you really did commit fraud you should look for legal assistance before trying to get a Canadian immigrant visa.

Answer (score 5):

The US and Canada share immigration data under the [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) arrangements. You can assume that the Canadians will know about the lifetime ban.

You're also asked on any visa application form if you've ever been refused a visa. Consequently, this ban will adversely affect every visa application you make from now on. Don't be tempted to omit the details. If the country you are applying to already knows then they will refuse you on grounds of deception and, as you have seen, the penalties can be severe.

If you are serious about migrating to Canada you should consider finding a Canadian lawyer with immigration experience to help you.

Answer (score 0):

the previous response is very detailed.
I have similar case with my brother. He did express entry on his own without a lawyer and he got PR. All you have to do is be honest in your application.

Comment: Had your brother also had trouble with the US immigration authorities?

Comment: Yes he had and was deported. He was deported and banned for 10 years but he made it to Canada 2018 only 4 years into the ban but he mentioned all in his application you just need to be honest because if you don't, they will find out

Comment: It would be helpful to include that information in the answer.  You can [edit](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/posts/22630/edit) it.